# Java bytecode instrumentation using ASM, MethodVisitor is null

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

So, with the code written below, my output is:

```
Starting application with the Agent
Visiting class: HelloWorld
Class Major Version: 51
Super class: java/lang/Object
Source: HelloWorld.java
Method: <init> desc = ()V cv = com.amir.agent.instrumentor.amirClassVisitor$1@79f1d448 and mv = null
Method: main desc = ([Ljava/lang/String;)V cv = com.amir.agent.instrumentor.amirClassVisitor$1@79f1d448 and mv = null
Method: foo desc = ()V cv = com.amir.agent.instrumentor.amirClassVisitor$1@79f1d448 and mv = null
Method ends here
Done instrumenting: HelloWorld
```

which is puzzling me.  Why would my `methodVisitor` be `null`?  The ASM source code seems to only return `null` for the `methodVisitor` when the `classVisitor` is `null`, which is not true in my case.

```
package com.amir.agent.instrumentor;

import org.objectweb.asm.AnnotationVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Attribute;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader;
import org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.FieldVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor;
import org.objectweb.asm.Opcodes;

public class amirClassVisitor {

    private byte[] outData = null;

    public amirClassVisitor() {
    }

    public void performInstrumentation(final String className,
                                       final byte[] classAsBytes) {
        final ClassVisitor cl = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM4) {
            @Override
            public void visit(final int version,
                              final int access,
                              final String name,
                              final String signature,
                              final String superName,
                              final String[] interfaces) {
                System.out.println("Visiting class: "+name);
                System.out.println("Class Major Version: "+version);
                System.out.println("Super class: " + superName);
                super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
            }

            @Override
            public void visitOuterClass(final String owner,
                                        final String name,
                                        final String desc) {
                System.out.println("Outer class: "+owner);
                super.visitOuterClass(owner, name, desc);
            }

            @Override
            public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(final String desc,
                                                     final boolean visible) {
                System.out.println("Annotation: "+desc);
                return super.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
            }

            @Override
            public void visitAttribute(final Attribute attr) {
                System.out.println("Class Attribute: " + attr.type);
                super.visitAttribute(attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void visitInnerClass(final String name,
                                        final String outerName,
                                        final String innerName,
                                        final int access) {
                System.out.println("Inner Class: " + innerName + " defined in " + outerName);
                super.visitInnerClass(name, outerName, innerName, access);
            }

            @Override
            public FieldVisitor visitField(final int access,
                                           final String name,
                                           final String desc,
                                           final String signature,
                                           final Object value) {
                System.out.println("Field: "+name+" "+desc+" value:"+value);
                return super.visitField(access, name, desc, signature, value);
            }

            @Override
            public void visitEnd() {
                System.out.println("Method ends here");
                super.visitEnd();
            }

            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(final int access,
                                             final String name,
                                             final String desc,
                                             final String signature,
                                             final String[] exceptions) {
                final MethodVisitor mv = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
                System.out.println("Method: " +name+ " desc = " +desc+ " cv = " +this+ " and mv = " +mv);
                return mv;
            }

            @Override
            public void visitSource(final String source,
                                    final String debug) {
                System.out.println("Source: "+source);
                super.visitSource(source, debug);
            }

        };

        final ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(classAsBytes);
        classReader.accept(cl, 0);
        System.out.println("Done instrumenting: " +className);

    }

    public byte[] result() {
        return outData;
    }

}
```

EDIT:

I call this code like this:

```
public class ClassLoadInterceptor implements ClassFileTransformer {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public byte[] transform(final java.lang.ClassLoader loader,
                            final java.lang.String className,
                            final java.lang.Class classBeingRedefined,
                            final java.security.ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                            final byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        if (!(className.startsWith("java") || className.startsWith("sun") || className.startsWith("com/workday/agent"))) {
            WorkdayClassVisitor v = new WorkdayClassVisitor();
            v.performInstrumentation(className, classfileBuffer);
            System.out.println("\t Instrumenting : " +className);
            byte[] instrumented_class = v.result();
            writeOutClassFile("debug", className + ".class", classfileBuffer);
            writeOutClassFile("debug", className + "_instrumented" + ".class", instrumented_class);
            return instrumented_class;
        }

        return classfileBuffer;

    }
```

Comment: How do you call the method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you print out is not “my `methodVisitor`” but the value returned by the `super` invocation of `visitMethod`, in other words the default value returned by [`ClassVisitor.visitMethod`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#visitMethod(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])):

> **Returns**:
>      an object to visit the byte code of the method, or `null` if this class visitor is not interested in visiting the code of this method.

Since the abstract class `ClassVisitor` does not implement any action, it has no interest in visiting the method and therefore `null` is the perfect return value.

So it’s up to you, to instantiate a new `MethodVisitor` implementing your desired behavior. Or, since you seem to intend to instrument a class, let your class visitor delegate to a [`ClassWriter`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html) which you pass to the [super class constructor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html#ClassVisitor(int,%20org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor)). This way you will inherit a replication behavior that you can customize. Then, `super.visitMethod` will return a non-`null` method visitor, which will replicate the method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  To confirm what you've said I created a new MethodVisitor and it seems to do what you're saying exactly.  What I still don't understand is the role of the ClassWriter.  Can you demonstrate how that would fit into the code I pasted above?